# Cannot call dynamic library (DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH) in R on Mac

Tags: r, terminal, imagemagick, rstudio, dyld

I cannot load my dyld libraries in R while it works in command line.

I ran `system('echo DYLM_LIBRARY_PATH')` in R and it returns nothing. This happens to both RStudio and R.

But when I ran echo `DYLM_LIBRARY_PATH` on terminal, it returns 
/Users/arthur/ImageMagick-7.0.7/lib/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not on a Mac at the moment, but it doesn't appear that you've told R you'd want that to capture any of the output anyway.

Let's fix that:

```
system('echo DYLM_LIBRARY_PATH', intern = T)
```

Proof using something I can run on my side:

```
head(system('ls')              # returns nothing
head(system('ls', intern = T)) # works
```

> ```
> [1] "01_02_rawAndProcessedData.pdf" "01_06_readingExcelFiles.pdf"   "01_07_readingXML.pdf"          "02_02_readingHDF5.pdf"        
> "02_03_readingFromTheWeb.pdf"  
> [6] "02_04_readingFromAPIs.pdf"
> ```

Comment: Thank you! Now the issue has been solved. But why I still cannot use `im.convert` in package `animation`? It returns 'Please install ImageMagick first or put its bin path into the system PATH variable', but I have already installed ImageMagick and it's bin path is also in the system PATH. Sys.getenv("PATH") definitely returns the path of `ImageMagick`. Sorry about this additional question. Thank you!

Comment: @Arthur Glad it works (better)! I would answer the additional question if I could, but I need more information. Could you open a new question with your example code?